# php get info from object

Tags: php, object

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["streams"]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["paramlive/_definst_/nakedbiz.sdp"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
      ["sessionsSanJose"]=&gt;
      int(0)
      ["sessionsCupertino"]=&gt;
      int(0)
      ["sessionsSmooth"]=&gt;
      int(0)
      ["sessionsFlash"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["sessionsRTSP"]=&gt;
      int(0)
      ["sessionsTotal"]=&gt;
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

What i expect to see.
paramlive/*definst*/nakedbiz.sdp - 1(this is from sessionsTotal)

Help me please guys, Thanks!

Comment: You want to see `nakedbiz.sdp` => google the first four letters, you'll see a lot of naked business :)... seriously, show some code, you did you get this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access properties by the following...

`$object->streams->{"paramlive/_definst_/nakedbiz.sdp"}->sessionsTotal;`